# code: 'missing_connection_string' any feedback would be helpful on this Next.JS project when I run yarn dev it doesn't load

Tags: next.js, hadoop-yarn

VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.

AND

code: 'missing_connection_string'

is the error I get when I yarn dev in the terminal.

I've tried changing stuff around in the .env file and .env.local such as adding the http://localhost:3001/ to the POSTGRES_URL: